Vue JS: сделать так, чтобы свойство active если true до перезагрузки, то оно должно остаться true после перезагрузки страницы
<date-button v-if="isTodayAvailable || isTomorrowAvailable" class="delivery-df__date-btn" :active="showCalendar" @select-date="showCalendar = true"/>

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+localstorage

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+сохранить+после+перезагрузки

<template>
  <date-button v-if="isTodayAvailable || isTomorrowAvailable" class="delivery-df__date-btn" :active="showCalendar" @select-date="toggleCalendar"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showCalendar: localStorage.getItem('showCalendar') === 'true',
      isTodayAvailable: true, 
      isTomorrowAvailable: true 
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleCalendar() {
      this.showCalendar = !this.showCalendar;
      localStorage.setItem('showCalendar', this.showCalendar); 
    }
  }
};
</script>


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
